# picklist - change the value of the items without changing what is displayed to the end-user

Tags: picklist

On HTML it is possible to have a different value than what the end-user sees. For example:

```
<option value="0.08">8 %</option>
```

Is there any way to accomplish this same idea with the default salesforce features?

Comment: What do you mean by default salesforce features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. What you need to do is:

- define your picklist values (eg. 001,002,003 and so on)
- translate values in the [Translation workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wbench.htm) or just give a standard (master) label for it

You will then get exactly what you want: values are defined in the picklist and labels are translations:

```
<option value="picklist value"> translation </option>
```

This is a standard salesforce feature that is easy to configure and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

In Visualforce there is component `apex:selectList`
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm

It's child element `<apex:selectOptions>` is referenced to `List<SelectOption>` in controller. `SelectOption` is class that contains label and value. Label id displayed for user, value is used in backend.

Or you can use single Visualforce elements `<apex:selectOption itemValue="red" itemLabel="Red">`
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOption.htm